# CloudFront + CloudFlare + Wordpress getting 302 redirects

Tags: wordpress, amazon-cloudfront

I just implemented CloudFront with Wordpress using W3TC. But none of my images are using the CDN. On checking Pingdom report I found that there is a redirection happening where CloudFront redirects back to my website.

```
 Remove the following redirect chain if possible:
https://cdn.fashioncrab.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/secure-footer-widget1.png
https://www.fashioncrab.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/secure-footer-widget1.png
```

Here is the PingDom report https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/vDTT0/https://www.fashioncrab.com/

How to fix this so that my images are called from CloudFront instead of my server.

Note: I have made the CNAME record for cdn.fashioncrab.com in CloudFlare if that helps...

Comment: CloudFront doesn't generate redirects.  If there is a redirect, it is actually being *generated by* your web server.  It is possible that in the CloudFront cache behavior, you whitelisted the `Host` header and you shouldn't have, or you didn't, but you should have.  A mismatch here might prompt your server to issue a redirect.  Check your server logs and you should see evidence of the 302s indeed coming from your server itself.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for looking into this. In CloudFront I have selected Forward Headers = All
Shou I use the whitelist function instead?

Comment: If you forward all headers, this disables the CloudFront cache, so I'd say yes, you should whitelist only the headers you need -- and `Host` should *probably not* be among them.  As a rule, every header you forward will lower your cache hit rate, because CloudFront (correctly) caches responses against the entire forwarded request -- not just the URL.

Comment: Ok, os I have disabled the header forwarding. Now the cloudfront URL simply goes to my website
d3kof2ht4afjz8.cloudfront.net > https://www.fashioncrab.com/

Answer (score 0):

So finally I am able to resolve it myself.
Here is what I did:

- Got rid of CloudFlare. Surprisingly, the site is much faster without CloudFlare
- Removed "Enable 301 .htaccess redirect" option from Really simple SSL wordpress plugin
- got a Free SSL certificate issued for the CloudFront distribution from AWS

Now everything is working as it should.